# Hudson - Building servlets with Ant (Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ant, hudson

I want to build my webservice via Jenkins running on Tomcat and deploy the war file on the same Tomcat. 
I have tested my `build.xml` in Eclipse Java EE version, it's compiling without errors. So I commited my changes to the repo and started a build in Jenkins. Dependent projects were build successfully, but javac was failed at compiling my Servlet, reason: Servlet class not found.

How can I set correct libs to build my app ? It's needed to download Java EE libs ? Or is it enough to have Tomcat installed ?

```
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /usr/share/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/SmartServices/HelloService/build/classes
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/SmartServices/HelloService/src/myservice/MyServlet.java:14: cannot access javax.servlet.GenericServlet
[javac] class file for javax.servlet.GenericServlet not found
```

Comment: What does the classpath element for you ant file look like? My guess is your eclipse classpath has the servlet-api.jar in it, but your ant script doesn't

Comment: Yes, the problem was at ant classpath, so I added `-lib /usr/share/tomcat/lib` param to script config. Now is everything running fine, thanks for your comment :)